# Read n bits (not bytes) in qt?

Tags: qt, binaryfiles

I'm very newbie in Qt. I have to read a binary file which contains a header. But in some positions I have to read 15 bits and 17 bits integers. Is there any functions to read n bits from a file in qt? 
PS: I read this file using Matlab by using ***fread*** and **ubit*n***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only read, and generally handle values in a minimum of 8 bits which is a char or 1 byte.

You can perform operations on single bit within a byte.

In your situation, you should read the sufficient amount of byte and then recast to a structure for instance.

[Bitfield](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm)

```
struct {
   unsigned double widthValidated : 15;
   unsigned double heightValidated : 17;
} MyStruct;

MyStruct * ptr = (MyStruct *) &myDouble;
```

You can also use bit shifting:

```
double myValue;
double a = myValue & 0x7FFF; // 15 first bits
double b = (myValue >> 15) & 0x7FFFF; // 17 bits after the 15 first
```

Answer (score 0):

Qt has a C++ interface. In C++, binary file access is octet-based. You can only read 8 bits at a time. So you'll have to assemble the integers in higher-level logic.

Comment: The sum of 15bits and 17bits is 32 which is  octet-based and how can I extract 15 and 17 bits and convert them into two integer in C++

Comment: Give us more information on your binary file, please. Are there always blocks of 32bits and you want to extract a 15 and 17bit number? What is the structure of the file?

Comment: @Paraboloid87 I found a bitwise operator solution for it, but as you told yes I have to decompose each 32 bit sections to 17 and 15 bits integer